# How to debug SPFx webpart debugging with Firefox

Tags: firefox, vscode-debugger, spfx

I have the misfortune to have users that "Must Have Firefox" and for some reason it does not perform the SPFx code the same as Chrome or Edge.
I am trying to debug with Firefox but none of the VS Code launch.json examples I found work for me and the browser shows the famous "run gulp serve" message. It is running.
I tried just the dev tools of Firefox but there is no webpack:// folder to get the source TSX files like I see in other browsers.

Anyone has some experience with debugging SPFx web parts with Firefox?
I am lost 
Thank you all

Answer (score 0):

This solution helps me with debugging SPFx in Mozilla: https://www.nubo.eu/SPFx-WebPart-Error-Loading-Debug-Manifest-copy.

It doesn't allow to fetch resources from *localhost* (even after *gulp trust-dev-cert*). In You need to go directly to your host where you're running spfx (it's https://localhost:4321 most of the time) and "Accept the Risk and Continue". It worked well for me.

Also, for debugging from VSCode in Mozilla you can use the [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=firefox-devtools.vscode-firefox-debug).